# Run method on component with Vuex

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, vuex

I have a [Vue component that contains a Leaflet map](https://github.com/haiafara/haiafara-ro/blob/3d256ce8b7299d3740c8723c4b0cab232d92d742/app/javascript/Map.vue). For the time being I'm using the event bus pattern to run some Leaflet methods when other components request it:

```
// in Map.vue
eventBus.$on('invalidateMapSize', () => {
  this.map.invalidateSize(true)
})

eventBus.$on('setMapView', (coordinates, zoom) => {
  this.map.setView(coordinates, zoom)
})

// in other components
eventBus.$emit('setMapView', [47.6623, 23.6970], 15)
```

Now I want to transition my app to Vuex and my question is how to achieve the same functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is true that there is a trend on using VueX and steering away from the event bus pattern, I personally find both patterns to be complementary.

VueX states match well with Vue component data/props and their derivatives (computed, watch).

But there are cases where you do not manage a state, but really some event: a user click that should trigger a one time action (and you do not care about recording such a change, so a state is useless / overkill for this purpose); a network response that carries temporary data (like a search result); etc.

For these cases, I still use an event bus, since the equivalent feature has been purposefully removed from VueX.

In your situation, it seems to me that it fits well in the latter case: Leaflet does not (only) display static data derived from some states (could be the case of Markers, Tile Layers...), but enables user interactivity where your app can interfere by forcing a view from time to time, based on some events.

Trying to achieve this functionality using states would very probably require recording the last requested map view in a state, watching that state, and triggering a side effect on state change. Then there is an issue when it is requested to re-set the view to the same position...